# R: efficient way to plot many plots in sequence with background image

Tags: r, shiny, r-raster, rgooglemaps

I am looking to plot a stop-motion animation of a sequence of plots in R.  These will show dots moving around on a trajectory.  I would like to show a map in the background so that the locations of the moving points correspond to the map coordinates.  The way I have been doing this is through RgoogleMaps, where I created a map object and then stored it as a png file, then I set it as the background of the plot using the rasterImage function.  Ultimately I am trying to have this be a shiny app (code below). 
The problem is that the animation speed I have in shiny is too fast (I can slow it down but it doesn't look as good), so the plot goes opaque because it can't process it fast enough.

Basically I want to show one set of points per iteration with the same background.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  Is there a way to, say, set the background image permanently without having to plot it each time.  I save some time by using recordPlot() and then replaying it, but it still doesn't completely solve the problem.  I have also tried seeing if I can make the raster lower resolution but the maxpixels and col arguments in as.raster don't seem to be doing anything for me.

I am not 100% sold on having to use GoogleMaps if there is a similar alternative that is much more efficient and will achieve roughly the same thing.

[BC_googlemaps_point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRcXY.png)

```
library(shiny)
library(colorspace)
library(raster)
library(grDevices)
library(png)

#a png from Google Maps of the area above
bc_longlat_map_img <- png::readPNG("BC_googlemaps_point.png")
bc_longlat_map_img_ras <- grDevices::as.raster(bc_longlat_map_img, maxpixels=100)

bbox <- matrix(c(33.68208, -118.0554, 33.70493, -118.0279), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2)
rownames(bbox) <- c("lon","lat")
colnames(bbox) <- c("min","max")

#make some fake data

pt_data <- matrix(NA,nrow=1000, ncol=2)
colnames(pt_data) <- c("lon","lat")
#length of each side
plot_dims <- apply(bbox,1,diff)
pt_data[1:250,"lon"] <- bbox["lon","min"] + 0.2*plot_dims["lon"]
pt_data[1:250,"lat"] <- seq(bbox["lat","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lat"],         bbox["lat","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lat"], length.out=250)

pt_data[251:500,"lon"] <- seq(bbox["lon","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lon"],     bbox["lon","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lon"], length.out=250)
pt_data[251:500,"lat"] <- bbox["lat","max"] - 0.2*plot_dims["lat"]

pt_data[501:750,"lon"] <- bbox["lon","max"] - 0.2*plot_dims["lon"]
pt_data[501:750,"lat"] <- seq(bbox["lat","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lat"], bbox["lat","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lat"], length.out=250)

pt_data[751:1000,"lon"] <- seq(bbox["lon","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lon"], bbox["lon","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lon"], length.out=250)
pt_data[751:1000,"lat"] <- bbox["lat","min"] + 0.2*plot_dims["lat"]

#this is the slowest, have to replot the whole thing each time
 for (ii in 1:1000) {
  plot(bbox["lon",1]-1000, bbox["lat",1]-1000, xlim=bbox["lon",],     ylim=bbox["lat",], xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude", las=1) 
   #read in current plots limits to fit Raster Image to
   lims <- par()$usr
   rasterImage(bc_longlat_map_img_ras, xleft=lims[1], ybottom=lims[3],     xright=lims[2], ytop=lims[4])
   points(x=pt_data[ii,"lon"], y=pt_data[ii,"lat"], pch=19, cex=3)
   }

#plot first, then record, and only replay each time
#seems to be a bit faster
 plot(bbox["lon",1]-1000, bbox["lat",1]-1000, xlim=bbox["lon",],     ylim=bbox["lat",], xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude", las=1) 
   #read in current plots limits to fit Raster Image to
   lims <- par()$usr
   rasterImage(bc_longlat_map_img_ras, xleft=lims[1], ybottom=lims[3], xright=lims[2], ytop=lims[4])
 plot_back <- recordPlot()

for (ii in 1:1000) {
   replayPlot(plot_back)
   points(x=pt_data[ii,"lon"], y=pt_data[ii,"lat"], pch=19, cex=3)

   }

 #example without the map background.  very fast.
   for (ii in 1:1000) {
    plot(bbox["lon",1]-1000, bbox["lat",1]-1000, xlim=bbox["lon",], ylim=bbox["lat",], xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude", las=1) 

    points(x=pt_data[ii,"lon"], y=pt_data[ii,"lat"], pch=19, cex=3)
   }
```

The shiny app I am trying to implement looks like this (code is repetitive):

```
shark_vis <- shinyApp(
    ui=  shinyUI(
     fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel("Inputs",
           sliderInput("iter","Progress of simulation",value=1, min=1, max=1000, round=TRUE, step=1,
                             animate=animationOptions(interval=100, loop=FALSE))),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
        )
    )
),
server=shinyServer(
   function(input, output) {
   #current image dimensions
bbox <- matrix(c(33.68208, -118.0554, 33.70493, -118.0279), byrow=TRUE,     ncol=2)
rownames(bbox) <- c("lon","lat")
colnames(bbox) <- c("min","max")

#make some fake data

pt_data <- matrix(NA,nrow=1000, ncol=2)
colnames(pt_data) <- c("lon","lat")
#length of each side
plot_dims <- apply(bbox,1,diff)
pt_data[1:250,"lon"] <- bbox["lon","min"] + 0.2*plot_dims["lon"]
pt_data[1:250,"lat"] <- seq(bbox["lat","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lat"],     bbox["lat","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lat"], length.out=250)

pt_data[251:500,"lon"] <- seq(bbox["lon","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lon"],     bbox["lon","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lon"], length.out=250)
pt_data[251:500,"lat"] <- bbox["lat","max"] - 0.2*plot_dims["lat"]

pt_data[501:750,"lon"] <- bbox["lon","max"] - 0.2*plot_dims["lon"]
pt_data[501:750,"lat"] <- seq(bbox["lat","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lat"], bbox["lat","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lat"], length.out=250)

pt_data[751:1000,"lon"] <- seq(bbox["lon","max"]-0.2*plot_dims["lon"], bbox["lon","min"]+0.2*plot_dims["lon"], length.out=250)
pt_data[751:1000,"lat"] <- bbox["lat","min"] + 0.2*plot_dims["lat"]

#plot and store 
plot(bbox["lon",1]-1000, bbox["lat",1]-1000, xlim=bbox["lon",],     ylim=bbox["lat",], xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude", las=1) 
   #read in current plots limits to fit Raster Image to
   lims <- par()$usr
   rasterImage(bc_longlat_map_img_ras, xleft=lims[1], ybottom=lims[3],     xright=lims[2], ytop=lims[4])
 plot_back <- recordPlot()


 output$plot <- renderPlot({
    replayPlot(plot_back)
    points(x=pt_data[input$iter,"lon"], y=pt_data[input$iter,"lat"],     pch=19, cex=3, col=1:2)
    })
    }
)
)   

runApp(shark_vis)
```

Comment: These may be helpful: [`gganimate`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate) and/or [`tweenr`](https://github.com/thomasp85/tweenr)

Comment: I'd like to stick with shiny for the "animation" part because I'm trying to develop an interactive tool for visualization where the parameters can be easily changed, rather than using code directly.  However, I tried ggmap and it is about twice as fast as the plotting I was using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package to 'simulate' an animation onto an actual Google Map.

I've simplified your example so I could get it to work, but the idea should translate to your example too.

Here I'm animating the route between Melbourne and Sydney

To do the animation you load a series of circles onto the map, then set the opacity to either 0 or 1 depending on which ones you want shown.

In this instance the ones you want shown are dependant on the value of the input slider.

The trick to avoid re-drawing the map and shapes each time is to load all the circles at the start, then use the `update_circles()` function to change the attributes (i.e., opacity) of the circles.

Notes:

- You need a valid [Google Maps Javascript API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/)
- The input data must be a `data.frame`, not a matrix
- I haven't found the 'break' point yet - i.e., the point at which there are too many circles that they can't update quick enough

---

```
library(shiny)
library(googleway)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput(inputId = "mySlider", label = "slider", min = 0, max = 222, value = 0, step = 1, 
        animate = animationOptions(interval=100, loop=FALSE)),
    google_mapOutput("myMap", height = 800)
)

server <- function(input, output){

    polyline <- "rqxeF_cxsZgr@xmCekBhMunGnWc_Ank@vBpyCqjAfbAqmBjXydAe{AoF{oEgTqjGur@ch@qfAhUuiCww@}kEtOepAtdD{dDf~BsgIuj@}tHi{C{bGg{@{rGsmG_bDbW{wCuTyiBajBytF_oAyaI}K}bEkqA{jDg^epJmbB{gC}v@i~D`@gkGmJ_kEojD_O{`FqvCetE}bGgbDm_BqpD}pEqdGiaBo{FglEg_Su~CegHw`Cm`Hv[mxFwaAisAklCuUgzAqmCalJajLqfDedHgyC_yHibCizK~Xo_DuqAojDshAeaEpg@g`Dy|DgtNswBcgDiaAgEqgBozB{jEejQ}p@ckIc~HmvFkgAsfGmjCcaJwwD}~AycCrx@skCwUqwN{yKygH}nF_qAgyOep@slIehDcmDieDkoEiuCg|LrKo~Eb}Bw{Ef^klG_AgdFqvAaxBgoDeqBwoDypEeiFkjBa|Ks}@gr@c}IkE_qEqo@syCgG{iEazAmeBmeCqvA}rCq_AixEemHszB_SisB}mEgeEenCqeDab@iwAmZg^guB}cCk_F_iAmkGsu@abDsoBylBk`Bm_CsfD{jFgrAerB{gDkw@{|EacB_jDmmAsjC{yBsyFaqFqfEi_Ei~C{yAmwFt{B{fBwKql@onBmtCq`IomFmdGueD_kDssAwsCyqDkx@e\\kwEyUstC}uAe|Ac|BakGpGkfGuc@qnDguBatBot@}kD_pBmmCkdAgkB}jBaIyoC}xAexHka@cz@ahCcfCayBqvBgtBsuDxb@yiDe{Ikt@c{DwhBydEynDojCapAq}AuAksBxPk{EgPgkJ{gA}tGsJezKbcAcdK__@uuBn_AcuGsjDwvC_|AwbE}~@wnErZ{nGr_@stEjbDakFf_@clDmKkwBbpAi_DlgA{lArLukCBukJol@w~DfCcpBwnAghCweA}{EmyAgaEbNybGeV}kCtjAq{EveBwuHlb@gyIg\\gmEhBw{G{dAmpHp_@a|MsnCcuGy~@agIe@e`KkoA}lBspBs^}sAmgIdpAumE{Y_|Oe|CioKouFwuIqnCmlDoHamBiuAgnDqp@yqIkmEqaIozAohAykDymA{uEgiE}fFehBgnCgrGmwCkiLurBkhL{jHcrGs}GkhFwpDezGgjEe_EsoBmm@g}KimLizEgbA{~DwfCwvFmhBuvBy~DsqCicBatC{z@mlCkkDoaDw_BagA}|Bii@kgCpj@}{E}b@cuJxQwkK}j@exF`UanFzM{fFumB}fCirHoTml@CoAh`A"

    df <- decode_pl(polyline)
    df$opacity <- 1
    df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

    rv <- reactiveValues()
    rv$df <- df

    map_key <- "your_api_key"

    output$myMap <- renderGoogle_map({

        google_map(key = map_key, data = df) %>%
            add_circles(radius = 1000, id = "id", lat = "lat", lon = "lon", 
                        fill_opacity = "opacity", stroke_opacity = "opacity")
    })

    observeEvent({
        input$mySlider
        },{

        r <- input$mySlider
        rv$df[r, "opacity"] <- 1
        rv$df[-r, "opacity"] <- 0

        google_map_update(map_id = "myMap") %>%
            update_circles(data = rv$df, radius = 1000, id = "id", 
                            fill_opacity = "opacity", stroke_opacity = "opacity")

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Screenshots

Starting state: showing everything

[image]

step 34 on the slider

[image]

step 44 on the slider

[image]

step 82 on the slider

[image]